# Format Dynamically Generated Column Headers Of GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, header, pivot

I have created a Stored Procedure in SQL which produces a pivot table.  I've successfully created a GridView in ASP.NET to display this data.

However, some of my column headings are dynamically generated from the data (AutoGenerateColumns=True), and those column headings are just dates, so they will look different almost every time the table is generated.

This all works fine, except that the date format of the column headings is wrong.  I know I could change the way SQL produces the dates in its output, but I don't want to do it that way.  I want to control it from the web page.

I didn't think this would be difficult - I thought I could just do something along the lines of finding the cells in the header row and changing the datastringformat.  The problem is that whether I put my code in the GridView's DataBound or RowDataBound event, the cells in the header row seem to be empty, so I can't reformat them.  It's as if the headers get populate some time AFTER the DataBound event, but I don't know when or how to trap it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the column headings during the "RowCreated" event. Here's how:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    e.Row.Cells(0).Text = Format(Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells(0).Text), "yyyy-MM-dd")
    e.Row.Cells(1).Text = Format(Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells(1).Text), "yyyy-MM-dd")
End Sub
```

I tested this against a GridView with dynamically/auto-generated columns and seems to work. Note that the columns are zero-indexed. Also that you don't need to specify row numbers to set the header cell's text.

Comment: I've tried this suggestion (thank you!). When I load the page I get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". I think this, again, is because at that point in the GridView's life-cycle the header hasn't been populated yet.

Also, when I simply entered [code]e.row.cells(4).Text = "Test"[/code] into the RowCreated event, I get the error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index". My GridView has 11 columns.  It will only work with an index of 0.  I don't know if this hints at the columns not having been created yet...